# androidx.room compil "The minCompileSdk"

Tags: java, android, gradle, build.gradle

I would like to use a SQLite database to store data locally with an Android app built with Java.

I've added the following dependencies :

```
implementation "androidx.room:room-runtime:2.5.0"
annotationProcessor "androidx.room:room-compiler:2.5.0"
```

into the file : "build.gradle (app)".

I've got the following error on compilation :

```
The minCompileSdk (33) specified in a
dependency's AAR metadata (META-INF/com/android/build/gradle/aar-metadata.properties)
is greater than this module's compileSdkVersion (android-31).
Dependency: androidx.room:room-runtime:2.5.0.
```

This value "minCompileSdk" seem to come from the file AAR metadata : [USER DIRECTORY].gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1...\room-runtime-2.5.0\META-INF\com\android\build\gradle\aar-metadata.properties.

I've opened this file, the value is well defined to 33.
I can't modify this value because the file is regenerated at each build.

#### I've already tryed the following solutions found on the web, without success :

- check if the "compileSdkVersion" and "defaultConfig.targetSdkVersion" is well defined to 31 => OK;
- check inside "Project Structure > Dependencies" if Android core === androidx.core:core:1.6.0 => OK
- Added the following code :

```
configurations.all {
 resolutionStrategy { force 'androidx.work:work-runtime:2.5.0' }
}
configurations.all {
 resolutionStrategy { force 'androidx.core:core:1.6.0' }
}
```

I've also tryed with "force 'androidx.work:work-runtime:2.5.0'"

Is somebody has a another idea ?

Thankz by advance and nice week-end to all,

Comment: Have you tried following what the error message says and changing your `compileSdkVersion` to 33?

Comment: damn... it was so obvious ! thank you ianhanniballake !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The compilation work fine after change the value "compileSdkVersion" and "defaultConfig.targetSdkVersion" from 31 to 33.

I've tried everything except the most simple and obvious way.

Thanks to ianhanniballake for opening my eyes.